# Simple SQL issues, cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong to get these errors - ORA-00942 / 907 / 922

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a supposed to be a simple SQL project, but I'm stuck on the first step. I've never worked with SQL before, so I'm pretty lost. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong that's causing these errors?

Here is the file:

```
   SPOOL output.log;

    DROP TABLE rental CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

    DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

    DROP TABLE customer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

    DROP TABLE distributor CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

    DROP TABLE rental_store CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;


    CREATE TABLE rental (   
        inventory_id        CHAR(10)        PRIMARY KEY,
        transaction_id      CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        late                DECIMAL(6,2),
        damaged             DECIMAL(6,2),
        fail_rewind         DECIMAL(6,2),
        taxes               DECIMAL(6,2)    NOT NULL,
        discount            DECIMAL(6,2),
        customer_id         CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONTRAINT rental_FK FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id));

    CREATE TABLE movie (    
        title_id_number     CHAR(10)        PRIMARY KEY,
        genre               VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
        actor               VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, 
        director            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
        awards              VARCHAR2(30),
        running_length      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        rating              VARCHAR2(5)     NOT NULL,
        year_released       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        media_type          CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
        inventory_id        CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        title               VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
        distrib_serial      INTEGER         NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        cat_mov_id          CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE));    

    CREATE TABLE customer ( 
        customer_id     CHAR(10)        PRIMARY KEY,
        name            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
        address         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
        tele_number     CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        rent_history    INTEGER         NOT NULL));

    CREATE TABLE distributor (
          distributor_name      VARCHAR2(30)    PRIMARY KEY,
          catalog               VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
          genres_offered        VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL));

    CREATE TABLE rental_store (
           store_name       VARCHAR2(30)    PRIMARY KEY,
           address          VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
           owner            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL));

    SPOOL OFF;
```

[image: Output from running it in Putty]
[image: Output part 2]

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name CASCADE;

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your script is erroring out all the over the place, such that even areas which should work could be failing.

Comment: You should tag only the db you are using .. remove the improper tag .. please ..

Comment: After pointing you in the right direction to clear the first of several errors in the script, since you are a beginner, allow me to offer some advice on style. First, trying to make all reserved words in upper case and all object names in lower serves no real purpose other than making your typing more difficult.  Just put it all in lower case.  Second, I'd move the final closing parentheses on its own line, column aligned with its matching opening parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors for the `DROP` statements are to be expected because the tables do not yet exist. You can safely ignore them.

Most of your problems come from the second closing parenthesis, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE movie (    
    ...
    cat_mov_id          CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE));  
                                                        ^ ---- here
```

You need to remove them. It is only needed in the first statement because of the column list of the foreign key.

The first (real) error you get is because you misspelled `CONSTRAINT` (you wrote `CONTRAINT`. The full clause needs to be

```
CONSTRAINT rental_FK FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
   ^ -- the "s" was missing here
```

However you can't create a foreign key constraint to a table that does not exist. So you need to change the order of the create statements to first create the `customer` table, **then** you can create the `rental` table.

Putting all that together, your script should look like this:

```
DROP TABLE rental CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE movie CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE customer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE distributor CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE rental_store CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE customer ( 
    customer_id     CHAR(10)        PRIMARY KEY,
    name            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
    address         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
    tele_number     CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    rent_history    INTEGER         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rental (   
    inventory_id        CHAR(10)        PRIMARY KEY,
    transaction_id      CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    late                DECIMAL(6,2),
    damaged             DECIMAL(6,2),
    fail_rewind         DECIMAL(6,2),
    taxes               DECIMAL(6,2)    NOT NULL,
    discount            DECIMAL(6,2),
    customer_id         CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT rental_FK FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE movie (    
    title_id_number     CHAR(10)        PRIMARY KEY,
    genre               VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
    actor               VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, 
    director            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
    awards              VARCHAR2(30),
    running_length      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    rating              VARCHAR2(5)     NOT NULL,
    year_released       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    media_type          CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
    inventory_id        CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    title               VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
    distrib_serial      INTEGER         NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    cat_mov_id          CHAR(10)        NOT NULL UNIQUE
);    

CREATE TABLE distributor (
      distributor_name      VARCHAR2(30)    PRIMARY KEY,
      catalog               VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
      genres_offered        VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rental_store (
       store_name       VARCHAR2(30)    PRIMARY KEY,
       address          VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
       owner            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL
);
```

---

Unrelated, but: you do not want to use the `CHAR` data type. It's more efficient and will give you less headaches if you use `VARCHAR` for every character column.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to show me where I went wrong. I see now how simple my mistakes were, but at the time I just couldn't figure it out. I just ran it through with your corrections with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the first time you run the script your DROP TABLEs will fail because you haven't created them yet.  That's to be expected and is acceptable in such a script.

Beyond that, if you are going to create FK relationships, you need to create the parent table before you create the child, which  you will see after you correct your misspelled key word.

I will leave it as an exercise for the student to take that clue and locate the mis-spelled key word in the first CREATE TABLE statement.